# Windows Anaconda couldn't get to install module Community

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install [this module](https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain/downloads) on Anaconda but I could not get to do it. When I download and run "conda install setup.py" command it didn't work. Isn't there a way to install modules without using easy_install(cause in this case the module can't be found on the default site)

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the exact error you get? Note that `setuptools` is not `easy_install`. Anyway, if all fail you just have to place your module directory inside the Python path or append to `sys.path` the parent directory of the module.

Comment: If you are happy to install the development version from the bitbucket repository, the easiest way to install is `pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain`

Comment: Sory I just couldn't get to try, somehow I managed to delete windows of my computer. So I started to using ubuntu. Thanks for your answers.